# What game does this screenshot of a western saloon/bar belong to?

Tags: pc, game-identification

[image: A cartoon-like saloon/bar]

Its a point and click western adventure game of some sort. It looks really awesome.

I tried looking on Google Images for hours but cant find the game.

Does anyone know it?

Answer (score 9):

After some searching, the game appears to be called "[The Bad, the Ugly and the Sober](http://www.adventure-archiv.com/t/uglyreviewe.htm)"

It seems to be a Russian game released in October 2007, and released in the US with a translation (English subtitles?) in January 2008.